# convert existing javascript file for requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I had a javascript file like below..
First, I have some functions defined, and call the function on some event (document.ready here)

```
function foo(arg) {
    return arg;
}

function bar(arg) {
    return arg;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    doSomething();
});
```

Now I am trying to use requirejs and having trouble figuring out how to modify this file for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this approach:

```
define(['dep'], function (dep) {  //If you have any dependency

    function foo(arg) {
      return arg;
    }

    function bar(arg) {
      return arg;
    }

    return {

      myMethods: {
        bar: bar(arg),
        foo: foo(arg)
      }

    };
});
```

You shouldn't include document.ready here. Instead use that where you are going to use this module as a dependency.

This module will return `myMethods` object containing your methods.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you would have two files, main.js, which contains the initial call to require, and code.js, which contains the code. What you can do is this:

in main.js

```
$(function () {

    require([
      "/Url_To_Code.JS_Here"
    ], function (
        code) {
          code.doSomething();
    });
});
```

in code.js:

```
define(
    [],
    function () {   

        var foo = function () {

        }; 

        var doSomething = function () {

        };

        return {
            doSomething : doSomething 
        };
    }
);
```

so whatever you export from code.js (what is returned), you can access in main.js